# ¿Como puedo instalar nodejs en una consola ssh?

Tags: linux, apache

Quiero instalar nodejs pero no me deja, me da error sobre el comando -f y me da invalido.

Lo instalo de esta forma:

```
  wget https://nodejs.org/dist/v6.9.1/node-v6.9.1-linux-x86.tar.xz
  tar -xvf node-v6.9.1-linux-x86.tar.xz
  mv node-v6.9.1-linux-x86 node
  cd node
```

Comment: ¿Que distribución estás usando?

Comment: Como? Siendo sincero, es la primera vez que lo hago y leei un manual de como hacerlo pero no resulta. Y lo intente de la manera que me remienda mi servidor y tampoco.

Comment: Me refiero a que distribución de linux estás usando, ya que puedes instalarlo directamente mediante su gestor de paquetes, por ejemplo, si es ubuntu puedes instar nodejs mediante `sudo apt-get install nodejs`

Comment: Entonces solo descargo el archivo y por el gestor de archivos o paquetes lo instalo. Se puede?

Comment: Si leei sobre eso, pero creo que no se puede.

Comment: Y además solo uso linux, aun no se si mi servidor sea ubunto. Por que no me da esas opciones en la consola.

Answer (score 2):

Si utilizas Debian o Ubuntu, entras a la terminal y tecleas lo siguiente:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Luego instalas el paquete nodejs

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs npm
```

Luego para ver si tenes instalado nodejs, tecleas en la terminal:

```
nodejs -v
```

npm es el manejador de paquetes por defecto para Node.js

Answer (score 1):

es directamente

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

Comment: Simplemente así, o necesito agregarle el url?

Comment: @AnimationsNow simplemente asi

Comment: Ok, gracias. Y pues ya leei otro manual y necesito hacerlo desde una pc, pues lo intento desde mi móvil y no da resultados. Es que no me deja escribir director en el panel. Y por motivos de seguridad o yo que se, mi servicio de hosting no sirve y no me deja conectarme desde FTP.